# noConflict is not resolving error

Tags: jquery

I am using group of libraries for jquery. I have created a single php file named(script.php) and included all jqueries libraries in this file. When ever or where ever I require Jquery I simply include this script.php file. Though Everything is going well but one my library is conflicing with other. IF I use $.noConflict() before `$(document).ready(function() {` or just after `$(document).ready(function() {` few other libraries start conflicting. My particular file that is giving error is, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>` It has following code. IS their anyway I can modify code or resolve problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
    fxAnimation:'slide',
    fxSpeed:'fast',
    className:'toggler'
});

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have another library using the `$` symbol, then you can restore the `$` to what it was before jQuery was run by putting this right after jQuery is included:

```
$.noConflict()
```

Then, you can just use `jQuery` like this instead of `$` and leave the `$` symbol for the other library:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
        fxAnimation:'slide',
        fxSpeed:'fast',
        className:'toggler'
    });
});
```

You can, of course make your own shortened symbol for jQuery if you want as in:

```
var $j = jQuery;

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
        fxAnimation:'slide',
        fxSpeed:'fast',
        className:'toggler'
    });
});
```

The important issue is that only one library at a time can be using the `$` symbol.  There are other workarounds such as this one:

```
(function($) {
    // in this block, $ is an argument variable that has been temporarily 
    // given the value of jQuery without interfering with the value of $ outside
    // this block of code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
            fxAnimation:'slide',
            fxSpeed:'fast',
            className:'toggler'
        });
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Using this my other which is whole plugin related to this library started giving error. `jQuery.toggleElementsShown is not a function`. Though problem is resolved frm this file. but started with other.

Answer (score 0):

The [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for jQuery.noConflict() says this:

> If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can
>   return control of  $ back to the other library with a call to
>   $.noConflict()

That means that as soon as you run `$.noConflict()`, the `$` variable is no longer an alias for `jQuery`. Thus this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

... is attempting to use the jQuery methods with some other library.

You probably want this:

```
// In the outer scope, we use jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // In this scope we can use $
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`jQuery.noConflict()` returns an instance of `jQuery`. Calling `noConflict` doesn't make any sense.

For your purpose of using `noConflict` would be

```
var $q = jQuery.noConflict(); //$q = independent instance of jQuery
$q(document).ready(function () {

    $q('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
        fxAnimation: 'slide',
        fxSpeed: 'fast',
        className: 'toggler'
    });

});
```

Comment: Interesting example, but I give you -1 for " _Calling noConflict doesn't make any sense._ ". If it makes no sense to you, then you are smarter than jQuery developers, because they did not deprecate this function yet (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). It is very useful function, defninitely useful sometimes.